# Firebase web authentication doesn't display in localhost

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I followed the documentation of firebase for add sign-in: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/firebaseui?authuser=0

Here the code for the login et the html for the display that I used:

```js
var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
    var uiConfig = {
        callbacks: {
          signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function(authResult, redirectUrl) {
            return true;
          },
          uiShown: function() {
            document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
          }
        },
        signInFlow: 'popup',
        signInSuccessUrl: 'dashboard.html',
        signInOptions: [
          //firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
          //firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
          //firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
          //firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
          firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
         //firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
        ],
        tosUrl: 'index.html',
        privacyPolicyUrl: 'index.html'
      };
      ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Login</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.1.0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.1.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.1.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.1.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>  
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/3.5.2/firebaseui.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/3.5.2/firebaseui.css" />
</head>
<body>
        <h1>Welcome to Login</h1>
        <div id='firebaseui-auth-container'></div>
        <div id="loader">Loading...</div>
        <script src="firebase.js"></script>
        <script src="login.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run my server on localhost I don't see the email authentication on my browser but when I just double click on my html page I can see it.
Here my errors in the console:

```
It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS SDK.
When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to only import
the individual SDK components you intend to use.

For the CDN builds, these are available in the following manner
(replace <PACKAGE> with the name of a component - i.e. auth, database, etc):

https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.0/firebase-<PACKAGE>.js
index.cdn.ts:18
[2019-05-31T18:13:57.308Z]  @firebase/app: 
    Warning: Firebase is already defined in the global scope. Please make sure
    Firebase library is only loaded once.
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: I added the errors of the console

Comment: Seems like you are importing firebase.js twice It already says `Please make sure
    Firebase library is only loaded once.`

Comment: I fixed this error but I always the same problem, I don't see the email authentication on localhost